# Managing the backstack with intent-created views (ie, camera, maps, ...)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

The default behavior of the backstack has fortunately not required me to write any special case handling of it for my app (though I do want to drop the very first screen still, which is the splash, but I'll figure that out).

However, now that I'm launching the camera and map with intents the "conventional" way (as separate processes/activites and not the new fragment/integrated style) via

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url));
intent.SetClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

StartActivityForResult(intent,(int)ActivityRequestCode.Map);
```

and

```
_imageFile = new File(_imageDir, String.Format("attachment_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_imageFile));

StartActivityForResult(intent, (int)ActivityRequestCode.Camera);
```

I'm running into some situations that I think are going to require some backstack mangment, and so was wondering
if there are some basic strategies for doing so.

**Issue 1**

When the camera returns (via the user pressing "done" in camera app), and control is returned to my app, and a view containing a viewpager is being displayed, the program crashes (flickers away and restarts) if the user scrolls the pager too soon after the camera closes (still need to duplicate in a controlled manner and get logs).

**Issue 2**

If I launch maps and then use the back button to return to my app, its current view seems to get duplicated on the stack. That is, after being returned to my app, if I hit the backbutton, the current view will be popped (confirmed by the "card slide" animation") and a copy of that same view will be next on the stack (so I basically have to hit back twice to get "out" of the view).

Is there some standard backstack functionality I need to build into my app to resolve this ?

Note: Ive seen the super, in depth slides on the backstack (well, the first half), and will post the link to it when I dig it up, and so am aware of the general docs for it.

Thank you.